# using different sbt files for the same project in different contexts

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there a way I can have different sbt build files for the same project and tell sbt which one to use? I can't seem to find any docs to suggest you can

Answer (score 0):

I found some info that I couldn't find in the docs in:

BasicCommandStrings.scala

by running 'sbt "help <"'

I simply run 'sbt < [build file name here] [command]', e.g.:

sbt < other.sbt publish